# iOS leaderBoard score not updated issue ios?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, gamekit, leaderboard, gksession

Now i have the leader board task in that i have submited my score through my sandbox account, the but my score updated after 18 hours and some delays only others can saw my score ....

i have implemented all the delegates... but still i am having the same issue...

any idea regarding this please share....

suggestions are highly appreciated...

Thanks in advance....

my code block :-

```
- (void) reportScore: (int64_t) score forCategory: (NSString*) category 
{
    GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:category];
    scoreReporter.value = score*50;
    [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSError *error) 
     {
         if (error != nil)
         {
             NSLog(@"reportScore: error!");

        }
        else
        {

                 NSLog(@"reportScore: successful!");
            [self callDelegateOnMainThread: @selector(scoreReported:) withArg: self error: error];
        }

     }];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, I've noticed that Game Center leaderboard scores don't show up until there are at least two scores. (Specifically in Sandbox, but this might also be true after release).

I've only tested this with two different accounts on two different devices, but two accounts on one device might work too.

Even then, there is sometimes a delay before scores are shown or updated.